# Code before setContentView trouble

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-view

My question is if it is possible to write code before `setContentView()` in the `onCreate()` method of the main `Activity`. In the code below I want to call the `setVariables()` before `setContentView()` but this causes my application to crash. If I call `setVariables()` after `setContentView()`, it works fine. Why is this?

```
package com.oxinos.android.moc;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;


public class mocActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public static String prefsFile = "mocPrefs";
    SharedPreferences mocPrefs;
    public Resources res;
    public CheckBox cafesCB, barsRestCB, clothingCB, groceriesCB, miscCB;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setVariables();
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mocPrefs = getSharedPreferences(prefsFile,0);
    }

    private void setVariables(){
        res = getResources();
        cafesCB = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cafesCheckBox);
        barsRestCB = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.barsRestCheckBox);
        clothingCB = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.clothingCheckBox);
        groceriesCB = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.groceriesCheckBox);
        miscCB = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.miscCheckBox);

    }
    public void submitHandler(View view){
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.submitButton:
            boolean cafes = cafesCB.isChecked();
            boolean barsRest = barsRestCB.isChecked();
            boolean clothing = clothingCB.isChecked();
            boolean groceries = groceriesCB.isChecked();
            boolean misc = miscCB.isChecked();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mocPrefs.edit();

            editor.putBoolean(res.getString(R.string.cafesBool), cafes);
            editor.putBoolean(res.getString(R.string.barsRestBool), barsRest);
            editor.putBoolean(res.getString(R.string.clothingBool), clothing);
            editor.putBoolean(res.getString(R.string.groceriesBool), groceries);    
            editor.putBoolean(res.getString(R.string.miscBool), misc);
            editor.commit();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, mocActivity2.class));
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Although the question has been answered adequately, just to explain that `setContentView(...)` perfoms something called 'layout inflation'. What that means is it parses the XML in the relevant file (main.xml in your case) and creates instances of all the UI elements within it. It then attaches that view to the Activity. When you call `findViewById(...)` it doesn't reference your main.xml directly - instead it references the content view attached to the Activity, in other words the one inflated by `setContentView(...)`.

Answer (score 10):

You can execute *any code you want* before the `setContentView()` method as long as it doesn't refer to (parts of) the `View`, which isn't set yet.

Since your `setVariables()` method refers to the contents of the `View`, it can't be executed.

Answer (score 1):

The `setContentView()` method sets the content of your XML file as the `View`, which is shown by the `Activity`.

You're calling `setVariables()` before you've specified any `View` to be shown.

That's why the error raises. The compiler doesn't know where that `View` belongs to. If you want to use a `ResourceView`, you have to set it first.