# Nullpointerexception when trying to read textfield - Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I have a button with a method that is invoked upon clicking.

The method:

```
public void addToList(View view) {
    System.out.println(1);
    String str = "";
    try{
     str = edit.getText().toString();}
    catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println(  ex );
    }
    System.out.println(2);
    new QueryInList( ).execute(helper, str);
    System.out.println(3);
    edit.setText(null);
    System.out.println(4);
    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
```

Well, I always get the exception, it is a Nullpointerexception.

This quite baffles me, because edit IS initalized:

It is declared in the class:

```
private EditText edit;
```

and besides, it is initialized in onCreate:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textfield);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
    ......}
```

So I wonder why I always get a Nullpointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the content view, before looking for the items. You dont have a view to find the items in until you set the content view.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textfield);

......}
```

Comment: You  are, of course, both right, I realized this might be the solution while I was typing the question.......sorry....

Answer (score 1):

Move `edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textfield);` after your `setContentView` statement.

Here is a nice explanation from user @Squonk from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153376/code-before-setcontentview-trouble):

> `setContentView(...)` perfoms something called 'layout inflation'. What that means is it parses the XML in the relevant file (*main.xml* in your case) and creates instances of all the UI elements within it. It then attaches that view to the Activity. When you call `findViewById(...)` it doesn't reference your *main.xml* directly - instead it references the content view attached to the Activity, in other words the one inflated by `setContentView(...)`