# NullPointerException while switching images based on device's density

Tags: android

I have a logo image that I display on the splash/welcome screen of the my app. When I recently made the app compliant to the xxx-hdpi screen sizes , I encounter a weird problem:

1. I created a bigger logo image with "_large" added to the name. I put that and the other image in `drawable` folder.
2. In the `onCreate` function of the activity, I'm checking device's density and opening the appropriate image:

```
float MAX_XX_SCALE = 3.0F; //Maximum scale of xx-hdpi screens.
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImg); // ImageView containing the image.
if (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density > MAX_XX_SCALE) 
    img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo_large));
else 
    img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo));`
```

But I'm getting a `NullPointerException` while executing the app.

This is my logcat

```
11-11 11:53:46.625: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
11-11 11:53:46.625: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
11-11 11:53:46.625: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
11-11 11:53:46.625: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
11-11 11:53:46.625: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-11 11:53:46.625: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-11 11:53:46.625: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
11-11 11:53:46.625: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 11:53:46.625: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-11 11:53:46.625: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-11 11:53:46.625: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-11 11:53:46.625: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-11 11:53:46.625: E/AndroidRuntime(919): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-11 11:53:46.625: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at com.project.android.WelcomeActivity.onCreate(WelcomeActivity.java:42)
11-11 11:53:46.625: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
11-11 11:53:46.625: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
11-11 11:53:46.625: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
```

This is what I have on line 42: `img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo));`

Comment: how many drawable folder containing that image and which are they ?

Comment: `img`is probably null. I don't think it has anything to do with your drawable, since it's perfectly fine to call `setImageDrawable(null)`. Check if your ImageView's id is correct

Comment: There are 7 folders, namely `drawable`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`, `drawable-xxhdpi`, `drawable-xxxhdpi`, and `drawable-nodpi`

Comment: ... and just in case, make sure the code you posted is called after `setContentView()`

Comment: what is there at line :42 in WelcomeActivity.java ?

Comment: @Su-AuHwang if the ID was incorrect, Eclipse wouldn't have let me compile the app. And, damn! I put it before `setContentView()`

Comment: @SweetWisherツ I put it in the question :)

Comment: @BasitSaeed as it is your typo mistake and you found the solution you should delete this question.

Comment: @SilentKiller What do you mean, typo mistake?

Comment: @BasitSaeed Eclipse would only complain if you the id isn't present in any layout file in your project, it doesn't mean you used this layout file for this specific activity.

Comment: @Su-AuHwang I put it before calling `setContentView()`. The issue's been solved, thanks :)

Comment: @BasitSaeed typo mistake as you're binding view before setContentView() too common issue and solution so you should delete your question else you wish. :)

Comment: @SilentKiller It is not a "typo mistake" to call a function between binding its view. I guess I will keep the question here as it might help anyone in the future. Thank you for your response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code before setContentView trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153376/code-before-setcontentview-trouble)

Comment: possible duplicate of [NullPointerException on findViewById() in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090185/nullpointerexception-on-findviewbyid-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you told

> And, damn! I put it before setContentView()

Therefore Your `ImageView img` is null because you are trying to `findViewById` before setting content view,So put

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImg);
```

after `setContentView` in your onCreate method because `R.id.myImg` is part of content view.

Comment: As suggested by you and @Su-AuHwang, this solved the exception. Thanks.